# Is the Global Administrator role required to manage Enterprise State Roaming in Azure AD?

Tags: azure, entra-id

As a new system admin, I was provided with access to some standard role assignments from the 365 admin center, which include the following:

- Authentication Policy Administrator
- Exchange Administrator
- Global Reader
- Groups Administrator
- Intune Administrator
- Security Administrator
- Service Support Administrator
- SharePoint Administrator
- Teams Administrator
- User Administrator

I'm currently testing the enabling of Edge Sync, which with our current P1 license, requires that Enterprise State Roaming be enabled. However, it's greyed out for me, so I was wondering if there were a specific role that would provide me with access to this.

If I do search for "roaming" on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference, nothing comes up, which may mean that it's not explicitly allowed based on any one role. We already have five Global Admins, so it was decided that I would be provided with individual role-based access and if there was something I needed to administer, I would be assigned the appropriate role.

Anything I have read regarding the management of Enterprise State Roaming says to log in as Global Admin and I have found nothing thus far that indicates this can be done without Global Admin. If anyone can verify if there is a different role that would allow this of if GA is a requirement, that would be much appreciated.

[Enterprise State Roaming Greyed Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A90gg.png)